# How to keep alignment consistent with non-LaTeX contents?

Tags: fractions

I am using "almost LaTeX" from the JetPack plugin for my WordPress blog where I post course work. How do I get the generated formulae to *centre* on the line so the equals sign lines up with the normal text that I have typed? to see what I mean please check [this blog entry](http://www.codejourneys.net/openuni/tu100-my-digital-life-block-2-part-5-session-1-3-using-numbers-to-cope-counts-activity-3/).

here are a the two offending pieces of LaTeX for the last two equations of the equations:

```
$latex = \large{\dfrac{1}{62,000}} $
```

and

```
\left(\large{\dfrac{10,000}{62,000,000}}\right) 100\% $
```

thanks for your time :)

Comment: I think this is going to get closed as 'off-topic'. Expertise in TeX is not going to help here, as the misalignment is caused by how web browsers deal with the placement of text relatively to images (which is what the LaTeX is converted to).